# Error in apache kafka Invalid sequence number for new epoch in ReplicaManager

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Apache kafka cluster with 5 brokers and 5 zookeeper servers.

I`m dont know why but at some days in log see such errors:

```
29 13:37:22 server kafka-server-start.sh[22648]: [2023-04-29 13:37:22,510] ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=4] Error processing append operation on partition message-topic-26 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
29 13:37:22 server kafka-server-start.sh[22648]: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.OutOfOrderSequenceException: Invalid sequence number for new epoch: 27732 (request epoch), 2 (seq. number)
```

Each my topic have 2 replica

Why this happen and how resolve this ?

I'm trying to reboot kafka brokers one by one - this is not helping.
I'm checking replication in console command - kafka-topics - all look normal. Each partition has 2 replica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should restart you producer.

> This exception indicates that the broker received an unexpected sequence number from the producer, which means that data may have been lost. If the producer is configured for idempotence only (i.e. if enable.idempotence is set and no transactional.id is configured), it is possible to continue sending with the same producer instance, but doing so risks reordering of sent records. For transactional producers, this is a fatal error and you should close the producer.

Sequence is a communicating mechanism between producer and brokers like TCP.
The producer send disorder sequence to brokers which can not handle it.After you restart you producer, a new sequence will be generated.

Comment: You think i`m must restart my "business" producer ? or all kafka brokers. My question is that thread name is Replica Manager , so that i`m think is some internal kafka errors. And i have this error in all partitions in all topic (about 10 different business application)

Comment: @PeterHomicevich your busniess producer. Let's explain like this: kafka brokers recivied sequence like 1, 2, 3, 4, and expect to recevie 5, but your producer send 3, then kafka throw the exception.
It's  internal kafka error, you are right, but on the producer side.

Comment: @PeterHomicevich, Are you sure this error occurs in all topic? Does every producer only sends messages to one topic or to all topic ?